# Mail merge seperate docs error: A field calculation error has occurred in data set 1

Tags: vba, ms-word

when i run the code, mail margin documents that have been executed correctly open. However, it is not saved and closed. I then get word documents in my desired folder but in this word document it just says

"A field calculation error has occurred in data set 1."

how can i solve that?

```
 Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = "C:\test\
  With .MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To 3
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Anlage")) = "" Then Exit For
        'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & "\"
        StrName = .DataFields("Anlage") & "_" & .DataFields("Anlage")
      End With
      On Error GoTo NextRecord
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With ActiveDocument
        'Add the name to the footer
        '.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore StrName
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
NextRecord:
    Next i
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @macropod can you help here, its your code :)

Comment: Field calculation errors are usually a result of an error in the field code itself or a problem where a particular value in the data source causes a problem with a field calculation (e.g. you divide by 0). Unless the VBA is actually inserting values into the mail merge main document (it doesn't look as if that is happening here), it probably isn't the VBA.